Is there any algorithm to calculate this ranking method quickly?
I want to rank the 20 teams in the English Premier League. Say that each team are assigned to the number 1 through 20, defining their ranking, no ties. There would be $20!$ number of permutations for the ranking assignment.
The final ranking would be the ranking assignment that minimizes
Loss = number of matches where the lower ranked team beats the higher ranked team
Among the 380 matches played in a season.
Does such a ranking algorithm exist? I tried an exhaustive approach, but iterating through $20!$ different permutations is very slow, I'm looking for a more efficient approach.

This could be performed fairly easily with python using the pandas library.

What do you want to happen when two teams each have the same number of wins and losses, at the end of the season?  How should that situation be handled?

This problem goes by several names: rank aggregation, minimum cost feedback arc set, linear ordering problem, Kemeny-Young method, minimum violations ranking.
You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows. Let $T$ be the set of teams, and let $P = \{i \in T, j \in T: i \not= j\}$ be the set of ordered pairs of teams.  For $(i,j)\in P$, let binary decision variable $x_{ij}$ indicate whether team $i$ ranks better than team $j$ in the final ordering.  The problem is to minimize the loss function $$\sum_{(i,j) \in P} \ell_{ij} x_{ij}$$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
x_{ij} + x_{ji} &= 1
&&\text{for $i \in T$ and $j \in T$ such that $i < j$} \\
x_{ij} + x_{jk} + x_{ki} &\le 2
&&\text{for $i \in T$, $j \in T \setminus \{i\}$, and $k \in T \setminus \{i,j\}$}
\end{align}
Do you have data you can share?

I used to have the matrix for a previous season but I've lost the data. I'll make the matrix for the season that's just ended when I have the time. Thanks for the names, I'll have some read on them.
